# imagemagick convert

Tags: linux, imagemagick

Нужно конвертировать изображение bmp 32x32 пикселя в одноканальное (только градации яркости) с глубиной цвета 256 уровней. И убрать метаданные из файла.

Сейчас файл вместе с заголовком весит 3210 байт. Это 3 байта на пиксель: `1024 * 3 = 3072` плюс заголовок.

Нужно, чтобы весил 1024 байта т.е `32 * 32 * 1 = 1024` – так, чтобы после конвентирования была только матрица пикселей, где на каждый пиксель приходится только 1 байт.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать, желательно, с помощью imagemagick?

Comment: Формат который вы хотите крайне не стандартный. Вряд ли есть что-то готовое.

Comment: Хотя можно попробовать `convert your.BMP  newname.GRAY` у них довольно дурацкая документация. Я смотрел тут http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Comment: У них лучше всего - это справка в самой команде: `convert -list Format`

Comment: Всем спасибо, что откликнулись. Я попробую вариант convert your.BMP newname.GRAY

Answer (score 1):

из комментариев:

---

Можно попробовать `convert your.BMP newname.GRAY`. смотрел [тут](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php).

У них лучше всего - это справка в самой команде: `convert -list Format`.